# Alternative to YouTube - Tubex app on Android

Tags: android, youtube

On iOS, I used to use the YouTube official app and then moved to [Tubex](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tubex-videos-music-for-youtube/id939906112?mt=8) when they brought the new user interface. I read somewhere that the new UI is the same they had for Android, but now that I’m planning to buy an Android device I wondering (among other things) what can I use to watch YouTube videos since Tubex is not available on Google Play. Tubex is very similar to the old YouTube app, besides I can search content using advanced options like duration and such.